# Java Method while-looping endlessly even though breakout case seems to be met

Tags: java, arrays, loops, while-loop, infinite-loop

I have a `while` loop whose loop condition is that a boolean variabke is true. The loop has logic in it to set the boolean variable to false when it's time to exit the loop. However, it never exits. I have confirmed by printing a message that the variable is being set to false.

Here is a précis of the method:

```
public void collapse(){
    boolean status=true;
    while(status=true){
        // some processing
        if (some condition) {
             System.out.println("Setting status to false");
             status = false;
        }
        // more processing that doesn't set status to true
    }
}
```

What's going on here?

Answer (score 2):

You're assigning status to true in the while statement, instead of checking for equality.  Either change it to status == true, or you could just use status.

Comment: wooooooooooow thanks a ton haha its been a long day of coding and i didnt catch that.

Answer (score 2):

You have an assignment in your loop condition `while(status=true)`.
To check the status just do `while(status)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
while(status==true){
```

Should be `==`

`=` is used to asign

`==` is used for comparison

Answer (score 1):

It's an anti-pattern to compare a boolean for this very reason - just evaluate it, ie change

```
while (status = true)
```

To

```
while (status)
```

Then it's easier to read, less code to write and has no chance of this kind of bug occurring.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the assignment operator `=` when you want to use the boolean compare `==`.

It should be:

```
while (status == true){
    ...
}
```

Comment: you need to have a little more explanation in order to collect reputation from others. this is just a comment

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
 while(status=true)
```

should be:

```
while(status == true)
```

A single `=` is an assignment operator and `==` is a comparison operator.